Nashorn hitting some sort of limit with binding values
I am using the openjdk version of Nashorn 15.4, tested with Java 21 and Java 11 with same results.
My code loads a Nashorn Script Engine binding values representing metadata fields and allows user to write Javascript to modify those metadata fields by passing the script to the eval method and then checking for modified metadata values. It was working fine but as I have increased the number of values added to the bindings I have unexpected issues that some binding variables values are missing or changed despite the script not modifying these values.
Screenshot to give some context

I am now able to mimic the problem with self contained example
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class JsTest
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
         int numberOfBindingVars = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         ScriptEngine engine;
         for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
         {
             engine = new org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
             for(int k=0;k<numberOfBindingVars;k++)
             {
                 engine.put("var"+k,"1963");
             }

             System.out.println(String.format("Bindings %d", engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).size()));
             for(int k=0;k<numberOfBindingVars;k++)
             {
                 if(engine.get("var"+k)==null)
                 {
                     System.out.println("Missing var"+k);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}

Running this with paramter 400 works fine and gives me
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400
Bindings 400

But if I increase parameter to 500 the binding count is inconsistent , although wierdly checking for each value doesnt reveal any missing.
Bindings 500
Bindings 499
Bindings 498
Bindings 497
Bindings 496
Bindings 495
Bindings 494
Bindings 500
Bindings 499
Bindings 498

And if run with 1000 I get inconsistent count again, also unable to find certain vars around the 500 mark
Bindings 1000
Bindings 999
Missing var448
Bindings 1000
Bindings 999
Missing var448
Bindings 998
Missing var448
Missing var449
Bindings 997
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Bindings 996
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Bindings 995
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Missing var452
Bindings 994
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Missing var452
Missing var453
Bindings 993
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Missing var452
Missing var453
Missing var454

In all cases works okay the first time, but with the 500 and 1000 calls thesubsequent iterations are incorrect.
More testing always fine with 448 bindings, and fails with 449 or larger.
Seems like there is some other Nashorn process trimming the size of the bindngs, this must be a bug surely?
Would love some input with deeper knowledge of nashorn

What Java version are you using? I don't know if it's relevant, but Nashorn was removed from JDK. Refer to JEP 372.

Version 21, but Im using the org.openjdk.nashorn.Nashhorn 15.4 instaled as third party package see https://github.com/openjdk/nashorn

Maybe you should [edit] your question and include those details. I think they are required in order to be able to reproduce your problem. By the way, I noticed the following in the screenshot you posted in your question: Made in W-Germany Does that mean West Germany? As far as I am aware, Germany has been united for around 30 years now.

Maybe but I tried with Java 11 as well, same error.

Java
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Project Tree
jsEngineScript
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── JsTest.java

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>js-engine-script</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jsEngineScript</name>
    <description>jsEngineScript App Project</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
            <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
            <version>15.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
    </build>

</project>

JsTest.java

static void forceGC() : perform garbage collection
showJVMMem() : Display JVM memory settings

package com.example;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;

public class JsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean enableForceGC = false;

        //default for loop = 10;
        int inputForLoop = 10;

        if (args.length >= 2) {
            for (int x = 1; x < args.length; x++) {
                if (args[x].equals("--enableForceGC")) {
                    enableForceGC = true;
                }
                if (args[x].startsWith("--inputFor=")) {
                    String inputForNum = args[x].substring("--inputFor=".length());
                    //System.out.println("inputForNum = " + inputForNum);
                    inputForLoop = Integer.parseInt(inputForNum);
                }
            }
        }

        showJVMMem();

        int numberOfBindingVars = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(">>>> numberOfBindingVars = " + numberOfBindingVars);
        System.out.println(">>>> inputForLoop = " + inputForLoop);
        System.out.println(">>>> enableForceGC = " + enableForceGC);
        System.out.println();

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine;
        //for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < inputForLoop; i++) {
            System.out.println(">>>> i = " + i);
            //engine = new org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
            engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

            int kct = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfBindingVars; k++) {
                engine.put("var" + k, "1963");
                kct = kct + 1;
            } //for k1

            System.out.println("i = " + i + "\tk count=" + kct);

            System.out.printf("i = " + i + "\tBindings %d%n", engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).size());

            // Traverse Bindings and output all variable names and corresponding values
            /*
            Bindings myBindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
            System.out.println("i = " + i + "\tbindings size = " + myBindings.size());
            System.out.println("i = " + i +"\tBindings List:");
            System.out.println();

            for (String key : myBindings.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key + " = " + myBindings.get(key));
            }
            */

            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfBindingVars; k++) {
                if (engine.get("var" + k) == null) {
                    System.out.println("Missing var" + k);
                }
            } //for k2

            engine = null;

            if (enableForceGC) forceGC();

            System.out.println(">>>>END i = " + i);
            System.out.println();
        } //for i

    } //main

    static void forceGC() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>>> run forceGC()");
        System.gc(); // Or use Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        // Wait a while to allow garbage collection to complete
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Pause 1 second
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void showJVMMem() {
        // Get a Runtime instance
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        // Output the total memory of the JVM
        long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        // Output the maximum memory of the JVM
        long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
        // Output the used memory of the JVM
        long usedMemory = totalMemory - runtime.freeMemory();

        // Get MemoryMXBean
        MemoryMXBean memoryMXBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();

        // Get heap memory usage
        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();

        // Output memory usage information
        System.out.println(">>>> Heap Memory Usage:");
        System.out.println("Initial Memory (Xms): " + formatSize(heapMemoryUsage.getInit()));
        System.out.println("Used Memory: " + formatSize(heapMemoryUsage.getUsed()));
        System.out.println("Max Memory (Xmx): " + formatSize(heapMemoryUsage.getMax()));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>>> JVM Memory Usage:");
        System.out.println("Total Memory: " + formatSize(totalMemory));
        System.out.println("Used Memory: " + formatSize(usedMemory));
        System.out.println("Free Memory: " + formatSize(runtime.freeMemory()));
        System.out.println("Max Memory: " + formatSize(maxMemory));
        System.out.println();
    }

    static String formatSize(long size) {
        String[] units = new String[]{"B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
        int unitIndex = 0;
        double sizeInUnit = size;

        while (sizeInUnit >= 1024 && unitIndex < units.length - 1) {
            sizeInUnit /= 1024;
            unitIndex++;
        }

        return String.format("%.2f %s", sizeInUnit, units[unitIndex]);
    }

} //class

Build
Build
mvn clean package

Download Libs
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs

Test
Test 1
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 1000 \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_1K_NoGC.txt

Test 2
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 10000 \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_10K_NoGC.txt

Test 3
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 100000 \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_100K_NoGC.txt

Test 4
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 1000 \
  --enableForceGC \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_1K_ForceGC.txt

Test 5
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 10000 \
  --enableForceGC \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_10K_ForceGC.txt

Test 6
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 100000 \
  --enableForceGC \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_100K_ForceGC.txt

conclusion
Let me give the conclusion first:

(a) Adding forced garbage collection to the for loop can avoid the problem.

(b) If you do not add forced garbage collection, given different paramter values, there will be different results. When testing paramter = 1000 (1K ), paramter = 10000 (10K), paramter = 100000 (100K) will have different results.


Test Result: Adding forced garbage collection

Test 4 : result_for_10_Binding_1K_ForceGC.txt
Test 5 : result_for_10_Binding_10K_ForceGC.txt
Test 6 : result_for_10_Binding_100K_ForceGC.txt

result_for_10_Binding_100K_ForceGC.txt
You can open the txt file and search for Missing. If no Missing appears, it means that you can use gc to solve the problem.
>>>> Heap Memory Usage:
Initial Memory (Xms): 500.00 MB
Used Memory: 0.00 B
Max Memory (Xmx): 7.81 GB

>>>> JVM Memory Usage:
Total Memory: 508.00 MB
Used Memory: 4.88 MB
Free Memory: 501.68 MB
Max Memory: 7.81 GB

>>>> numberOfBindingVars = 100000
>>>> inputForLoop = 10
>>>> enableForceGC = true

>>>> i = 0
i = 0   k count=100000
i = 0   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 0

>>>> i = 1
i = 1   k count=100000
i = 1   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 1

>>>> i = 2
i = 2   k count=100000
i = 2   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 2

>>>> i = 3
i = 3   k count=100000
i = 3   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 3

>>>> i = 4
i = 4   k count=100000
i = 4   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 4

>>>> i = 5
i = 5   k count=100000
i = 5   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 5

>>>> i = 6
i = 6   k count=100000
i = 6   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 6

>>>> i = 7
i = 7   k count=100000
i = 7   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 7

>>>> i = 8
i = 8   k count=100000
i = 8   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 8

>>>> i = 9
i = 9   k count=100000
i = 9   Bindings 100000

>>>> run forceGC()
>>>>END i = 9

Test Result: default , no force garbage collection

Test 1 : result_for_10_Binding_1K_NoGC.txt
Test 2 : result_for_10_Binding_10K_NoGC.txt
Test 3 : result_for_10_Binding_100K_NoGC.txt

I have to tell you, interesting results occurred.
Test 1 : result_for_10_Binding_1K_NoGC.txt
Found Missing : 29 times, when for loop = 10, input parameter is 1000 (1K).
>>>> Heap Memory Usage:
Initial Memory (Xms): 500.00 MB
Used Memory: 0.00 B
Max Memory (Xmx): 7.81 GB

>>>> JVM Memory Usage:
Total Memory: 508.00 MB
Used Memory: 4.88 MB
Free Memory: 501.68 MB
Max Memory: 7.81 GB

>>>> numberOfBindingVars = 1000
>>>> inputForLoop = 10
>>>> enableForceGC = false

>>>> i = 0
i = 0   k count=1000
i = 0   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 0

>>>> i = 1
i = 1   k count=1000
i = 1   Bindings 999
Missing var448
>>>>END i = 1

>>>> i = 2
i = 2   k count=1000
i = 2   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 2

>>>> i = 3
i = 3   k count=1000
i = 3   Bindings 999
Missing var448
>>>>END i = 3

>>>> i = 4
i = 4   k count=1000
i = 4   Bindings 998
Missing var448
Missing var449
>>>>END i = 4

>>>> i = 5
i = 5   k count=1000
i = 5   Bindings 997
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
>>>>END i = 5

>>>> i = 6
i = 6   k count=1000
i = 6   Bindings 996
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
>>>>END i = 6

>>>> i = 7
i = 7   k count=1000
i = 7   Bindings 995
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Missing var452
>>>>END i = 7

>>>> i = 8
i = 8   k count=1000
i = 8   Bindings 994
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Missing var452
Missing var453
>>>>END i = 8

>>>> i = 9
i = 9   k count=1000
i = 9   Bindings 993
Missing var448
Missing var449
Missing var450
Missing var451
Missing var452
Missing var453
Missing var454
>>>>END i = 9

Test 2 : result_for_10_Binding_10K_NoGC.txt
Found Missing :  1 times, when for loop = 10, input parameter is 10000 (10K).
>>>> Heap Memory Usage:
Initial Memory (Xms): 500.00 MB
Used Memory: 0.00 B
Max Memory (Xmx): 7.81 GB

>>>> JVM Memory Usage:
Total Memory: 508.00 MB
Used Memory: 4.88 MB
Free Memory: 501.68 MB
Max Memory: 7.81 GB

>>>> numberOfBindingVars = 10000
>>>> inputForLoop = 10
>>>> enableForceGC = false

>>>> i = 0
i = 0   k count=10000
i = 0   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 0

>>>> i = 1
i = 1   k count=10000
i = 1   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 1

>>>> i = 2
i = 2   k count=10000
i = 2   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 2

>>>> i = 3
i = 3   k count=10000
i = 3   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 3

>>>> i = 4
i = 4   k count=10000
i = 4   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 4

>>>> i = 5
i = 5   k count=10000
i = 5   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 5

>>>> i = 6
i = 6   k count=10000
i = 6   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 6

>>>> i = 7
i = 7   k count=10000
i = 7   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 7

>>>> i = 8
i = 8   k count=10000
i = 8   Bindings 9999
Missing var448
>>>>END i = 8

>>>> i = 9
i = 9   k count=10000
i = 9   Bindings 10000
>>>>END i = 9

Test 3 : result_for_10_Binding_100K_NoGC.txt
Found Missing :  0 times, when for loop = 10, input parameter is 100000 (100K).
>>>> Heap Memory Usage:
Initial Memory (Xms): 500.00 MB
Used Memory: 0.00 B
Max Memory (Xmx): 7.81 GB

>>>> JVM Memory Usage:
Total Memory: 508.00 MB
Used Memory: 4.88 MB
Free Memory: 501.68 MB
Max Memory: 7.81 GB

>>>> numberOfBindingVars = 100000
>>>> inputForLoop = 10
>>>> enableForceGC = false

>>>> i = 0
i = 0   k count=100000
i = 0   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 0

>>>> i = 1
i = 1   k count=100000
i = 1   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 1

>>>> i = 2
i = 2   k count=100000
i = 2   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 2

>>>> i = 3
i = 3   k count=100000
i = 3   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 3

>>>> i = 4
i = 4   k count=100000
i = 4   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 4

>>>> i = 5
i = 5   k count=100000
i = 5   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 5

>>>> i = 6
i = 6   k count=100000
i = 6   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 6

>>>> i = 7
i = 7   k count=100000
i = 7   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 7

>>>> i = 8
i = 8   k count=100000
i = 8   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 8

>>>> i = 9
i = 9   k count=100000
i = 9   Bindings 100000
>>>>END i = 9

When the input parameters change from 1000 (1K) to 100000 (100K), the number of errors drops to 0. This is an interesting result.
Test Some parameters
Example:
java \
 -Xmx512m \
 -Xms256m \
 -Xss1m \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 6000 \
  --inputFor=20 \
  --enableForceGC


--inputFor=20 , for loop default is 10. you can config for loop to 1 or 20.
--enableForceGC, you can add this to force gc.

You can also adjust the memory settings of the JVM:

-Xmx512m
-Xms256m
-Xss1m

You can keep adjusting the memory settings to see if it has any impact.

Thankyo for that, very interesting, but would be great if someone on nashorn team could explain why it is happening in first place.

I gave another answer, using GraalVM JS to test.

I cannot switch to a Graal version of Java because one of the platform i support is Java ARm32 which is not supported by Graal.

Another Version using GraalVM JS
Java
install GraalVM Oracle - 24.ea.15-graal
$ sdk install java java 24.ea.15-graal

Check java version
$ java -version
java version "24" 2025-03-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 24-dev+17.1 (build 24+17-jvmci-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 24-dev+17.1 (build 24+17-jvmci-b01, mixed mode, sharing)


Project Tree
jsEngineScript_GraalVM_JS
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── JsTest.java

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>graalvm-js-engine-script</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>graalvm-jsEngineScript</name>
    <description>graalvm-jsEngineScript App Project</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compiler.encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId>
            <artifactId>polyglot</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.polyglot</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-community</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
    </build>

</project>

JsTest.java

static void forceGC() : perform garbage collection
showJVMMem() : Display JVM memory settings

package com.example;

import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean;
import java.lang.management.MemoryUsage;

public class JsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean enableForceGC = false;

        //default for loop = 10;
        int inputForLoop = 10;

        if (args.length >= 2) {
            for (int x = 1; x < args.length; x++) {
                if (args[x].equals("--enableForceGC")) {
                    enableForceGC = true;
                }
                if (args[x].startsWith("--inputFor=")) {
                    String inputForNum = args[x].substring("--inputFor=".length());
                    //System.out.println("inputForNum = " + inputForNum);
                    inputForLoop = Integer.parseInt(inputForNum);
                }
            }
        }

        showJVMMem();

        int numberOfBindingVars = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(">>>> numberOfBindingVars = " + numberOfBindingVars);
        System.out.println(">>>> inputForLoop = " + inputForLoop);
        System.out.println(">>>> enableForceGC = " + enableForceGC);
        System.out.println();

        //ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        Context context = Context.create();
        //ScriptEngine engine;
        Value engine;
        //for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < inputForLoop; i++) {
            System.out.println(">>>> i = " + i);
            //engine = new org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
            //engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            engine = context.getBindings("js");
            int kct = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfBindingVars; k++) {
                //engine.put("var" + k, "1963");
                engine.putMember("var" + k, "1963");
                kct = kct + 1;
                // Run JS Script Example
                /*
                String JS_CODE = "(function myFun(param){console.log('Hello ' + param + ' from JS');})";
                String who = "World";
                Value value = context.eval("js", JS_CODE);
                value.execute(who + " at "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                 */
            } //for k1

            System.out.println("i = " + i + "\tk count=" + kct);

            //System.out.printf("i = " + i + "\tBindings %d%n", engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).size());
            System.out.printf("i = " + i + "\tBindings %d%n", engine.getMemberKeys().size());

            // Traverse Bindings and output all variable names and corresponding values
            /*
            Bindings myBindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
            System.out.println("i = " + i + "\tbindings size = " + myBindings.size());
                        
            System.out.println("i = " + i +"\tBindings List:");
            System.out.println();

            for (String key : myBindings.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key + " = " + myBindings.get(key));
            }
            */

            for (int k = 0; k < numberOfBindingVars; k++) {
                // if (engine.get("var" + k) == null) {
                if (engine.getMember("var" + k) == null) {
                    System.out.println("Missing var" + k);
                }
                /*
                else {
                    System.out.println("var" + k + " = "+engine.getMember("var" + k));
                }
                 */
            } //for k2

            engine = null;

            if (enableForceGC) forceGC();

            System.out.println(">>>>END i = " + i);
            System.out.println();
        } //for i

    } //main

    static void forceGC() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>>> run forceGC()");
        System.gc(); // Or use Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        // Wait a while to allow garbage collection to complete
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Pause 1 second
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void showJVMMem() {
        // Get a Runtime instance
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        // Output the total memory of the JVM
        long totalMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        // Output the maximum memory of the JVM
        long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
        // Output the used memory of the JVM
        long usedMemory = totalMemory - runtime.freeMemory();

        // Get MemoryMXBean
        MemoryMXBean memoryMXBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();

        // Get heap memory usage
        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();

        // Output memory usage information
        System.out.println(">>>> Heap Memory Usage:");
        System.out.println("Initial Memory (Xms): " + formatSize(heapMemoryUsage.getInit()));
        System.out.println("Used Memory: " + formatSize(heapMemoryUsage.getUsed()));
        System.out.println("Max Memory (Xmx): " + formatSize(heapMemoryUsage.getMax()));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>>> JVM Memory Usage:");
        System.out.println("Total Memory: " + formatSize(totalMemory));
        System.out.println("Used Memory: " + formatSize(usedMemory));
        System.out.println("Free Memory: " + formatSize(runtime.freeMemory()));
        System.out.println("Max Memory: " + formatSize(maxMemory));
        System.out.println();
    }

    static String formatSize(long size) {
        String[] units = new String[]{"B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"};
        int unitIndex = 0;
        double sizeInUnit = size;

        while (sizeInUnit >= 1024 && unitIndex < units.length - 1) {
            sizeInUnit /= 1024;
            unitIndex++;
        }

        return String.format("%.2f %s", sizeInUnit, units[unitIndex]);
    }

} //class


Build
Build
mvn clean package

Download Libs
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs

Test
Test 1
java \
  --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 1000 \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_1K_NoGC.txt

Test 2
java \
  --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 10000 \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_10K_NoGC.txt

Test 3
java \
  --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 100000 \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_100K_NoGC.txt

Test 4
java \
  --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 1000 \
  --enableForceGC \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_1K_ForceGC.txt

Unlike using the nashorn version, the situation using GraalVM JS looks normal. Missing did not appear.
result_for_10_Binding_1K_NoGC.txt
>>>> Heap Memory Usage:
Initial Memory (Xms): 500.00 MB
Used Memory: 4.99 MB
Max Memory (Xmx): 7.81 GB

>>>> JVM Memory Usage:
Total Memory: 504.00 MB
Used Memory: 6.70 MB
Free Memory: 496.33 MB
Max Memory: 7.81 GB

>>>> numberOfBindingVars = 1000
>>>> inputForLoop = 10
>>>> enableForceGC = false

>>>> i = 0
i = 0   k count=1000
i = 0   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 0

>>>> i = 1
i = 1   k count=1000
i = 1   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 1

>>>> i = 2
i = 2   k count=1000
i = 2   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 2

>>>> i = 3
i = 3   k count=1000
i = 3   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 3

>>>> i = 4
i = 4   k count=1000
i = 4   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 4

>>>> i = 5
i = 5   k count=1000
i = 5   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 5

>>>> i = 6
i = 6   k count=1000
i = 6   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 6

>>>> i = 7
i = 7   k count=1000
i = 7   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 7

>>>> i = 8
i = 8   k count=1000
i = 8   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 8

>>>> i = 9
i = 9   k count=1000
i = 9   Bindings 1000
>>>>END i = 9


Test 5
java \
  --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 10000 \
  --enableForceGC \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_10K_ForceGC.txt

Test 6
java \
  --enable-native-access=ALL-UNNAMED \
  -Dpolyglotimpl.DisableVersionChecks=true \
  -cp "target/libs/*:target/app.jar" \
  com.example.JsTest 100000 \
  --enableForceGC \
  >> result_for_10_Binding_100K_ForceGC.txt

conclusion
It seems that there will be no missing binding objects when using GraalVM JS.
